# Uploading data from csv to MYSQL Server using MYSQLSH

Tags: mysql

I need to upload data from CSV to my MYSQL Server, I've used mysqlsh to do it using jobs:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Shell\bin\mysqlsh.exe" --sql -h x.x.x.x -u user -password -D database -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (field1, field2)
```

But when i execute the command i got this error:

> The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

I readed that i need to set local_infile to TRUE, i've made and i can't do it
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the mysql server version you are using?

Comment: do that with out the shell

Comment: 5.7.30 version on server

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `local_infile` option on client side, as well. The only way to do that in MySQL Shell is to pass that option as connection option.

`mysqlsh.exe mysql://user@x.x.x.x/database?local-infile=1 -e "LOAD DATA..."`

You can get more information about connection options by calling `mysqlsh -i -e "\? connection"`.

If you want to load big input CSV file, you can use [MySQL Shell's Parallel data import](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-parallel-table.html).

Comment: How 'big' a file has to be for it to be called a 'big input CSV file'? Or is it just subjective?